# Android Branch IO deep link does not open my application

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I have created simple application with one `Activity` and with manifest like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kz.ant.branchio">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MyApp">

        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_XXXXXXXXXXX" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="branchiotestapp" android:host="open" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my `key_live_XXXXXXXXXXX` I have pasted my dashboards live key.

Then in my application I have added this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` has these lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...
            } else {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

My application URI scheme is `branchiotestapp://` which I understood is when user clicks link with this scheme, it should open my application. Then I have created simple HTML web page with this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="branchiotestapp://mysite.com">CLICK</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this HTML with my phone browser and clickt to this link, my android application **DOES NOT OPEN even if it is installed**

Why is this happening? Did I misunderstood how branch.io works?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the link you are putting on the web page.

When using Branch you do not construct your own intent strings: you use Branch links. You can create Branch links from your app's Branch dashboard, on the Marketing page (here: https://dashboard.branch.io/marketing); within your mobile app by using Branch SDK calls; or by appending query parameters to your Branch link domain (which can be found at the bottom of the Link Settings page on the dashboard, here: https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link). A full description of the various methods can be found here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/overview/

Regarding the specific intent string that you have put on your web page, you have not defined any intent-filter or activity to handle the "mysite.com" URI path. Replacing this URI path with "open" may get the link working, but I would recommend creating Branch links as the best approach here.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see you are missing single task launch mode with your activity please assign

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

It is mentioned in branch io integration and you can see https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration if you have missed any other thing too.

Single Task launch mode required
The Single Task mode instantiates the Main/Splash Activity only if it does not exist in the Activity Stack.

If the Activity exists in the background, every subsequent intent to the Activity just brings it to the foreground.